# Adding other UI elements to UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, user-interaction

When I add an accessoryView to a UITableViewCell like so:

```
cell.accessoryView = myTextField;
```

I have to set the cell userInteractionEnabled to YES. The problem is, I don't want the cell's interaction enabled to be YES, only the textField's. I tried this:

```
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
myTextField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

but because the text field is a subview of the UITableViewCell, that doesn't have the desired effect.

So my question is: how can I enable interaction with a UI element within a UITableViewCell without enabling interaction with the cell itself? i.e. when the user presses the cell, I don't want it to turn blue, but I still want them to be able to edit the text within the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the user presses the cell, I don't want it to turn blue

You can achieve this by setting the selection style of the cell to none (in IB) or, in code, `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`. There is no need to disable interaction on the cell.